# How to correctly maintain the cursor position in Redactor?

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, redactor

I am writing a custom plugin for redactor to insert icons (read font awesome icons). The problem is, the icon always gets inserted at the start of the content rather than at the previous cursor position.

The Icon plugin written by me:

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.icons = {
    init: function()
    {
        var icons = '&#xf000; &#xf001; &#xf002;';
        var name = 'icons';
        var $dropdown = $('<div class="redactor_dropdown redactor_dropdown_box_' + name + '" style="display: none; width: 243px;">');

        this.buttonAddSeparator();
        this.iconPickerBuilder($dropdown, name, icons);
        $(this.$toolbar).append($dropdown);
        this.buttonAdd(name, this.opts.curLang[name], $.proxy(function(btnName, $button, btnObject, e)
        {
            this.selectionSave();
            this.dropdownShow(e, btnName);
        }, this));
    },
    iconPickerBuilder: function($dropdown, name, icons)
    {
        var _self = this;
        var onSwatch = function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            _self.iconPickerSet($(this).text());
        }

        var ilist = icons.split(' ');
        var len = ilist.length;
        for (var z = 0; z < len; z++)
        {
            var icon = ilist[z];

            var $swatch = $('<i class="fa" style="margin-right: 10px">' + icon + '</i>');
            $dropdown.append($swatch);
            $swatch.on('click', onSwatch);
        }
    },
    iconPickerSet: function(c)
    {
        this.bufferSet();
        this.$editor.focus();
        this.selectionRestore();

        var node = $('<i class="fa">' + c + '</i>');
        this.insertNode(node);
        this.sync();
    }
};
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test right now, but calling `this.$editor.focus()` might set the focus on the wrong element when restoring the selection. According to the examples, just calling `this.selectionRestore()` should be enough: http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/plugin-modal/

Have you tried it without the `this.$editor.focus()` statement?

Another thing I take away from the example is that they don't call the `this.selectionSave()` from the `this.buttonAdd` callback, but rather when creating the modal dialog (in their case). It's really hard to tell whether the modal behaviour would be different from the dropdown behaviour, but you could try using a modal and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: the bufferSet was not playing well, removing that solved the problem